# Remove stroke from one side of SVG using stroke-dasharray

Tags: html, css, svg

I am wondering is there a way have border (or stroke) all around except on the right side of the star (maybe using `stroke-dasharray`)?

SVG:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="SvgDefinitions">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="HalfStar" viewBox="0 0 20 19">
      <path d="M9,0.6L6.5,5.7L0.9,6.5c-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.6,0.3c-0.4,0.4-0.4,1,0,1.4l4.1,4l-1,5.6c0,0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.6 c0.3,0.5,0.9,0.7,1.4,0.4l5.1-2.7l0,0V0C9.6,0,9.2,0.2,9,0.6z" />
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>

<svg class="Star-Container">
  <use href="#HalfStar" x-link:href="#HalfStar" />
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
#HalfStar {
  stroke: red;
  stroke-dasharray: 5,4;
}
```

[image]

CodePen: https://codepen.io/amir734jj/pen/zYqWZRN

Comment: I would like to ask a question to the person who puts a minus What you did not like in my answer where the solution is given with detailed explanations. Maybe I did something wrong?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT I think the question was how to have border only on the left of the half star and no border on the right of the star (no straight line on the right). None of your solution satisfies the original question

Comment: @Apha The first solution without the border on the right side fully answered the author's question Second solution added per NodeJS comment

Comment: Your solution doesn't have a continuous border on the left. It's dashed. I think the OP wanted continuous border on the left and no border on the right.

Comment: @ Apha I can make a solution like in your comment But the author's question was - `I am wondering is there a way have border (or stroke) all around except on the right side of the star` I would like to hear the opinion of the author what exactly he needs

Comment: @Alexandr_TT I also understand it as they wanted something like `33px, 16px`.

Comment: @Kaiido Misleading example of author with dashes and no clear description of what he wants I will make an additional example

Comment: Sounds quite clear to me that they only used dashes as an attempt to achieve the *"border (or stroke) all around except on the right side"*. In their description nothing else mentions dashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The total length of the contour of half of the star measured with `getTotalLength()` is - `50px`
The vertical bar length of the star is - `16px`
For this segment, `stroke-dasharray =" 0 16 "` where `0` is the length of the stroke `16` is the length of the space

Therefore, the area of the star that should be filled with strokes is `34px`

For 5 groups of strokes and spaces - `34/10 = 3,4px`

As a result, the general formula will be:

```
stroke-dasharray="3.4,3.4 3.4,3.4 3.4,3.4 3.4,3.4 3.4,3.4 0, 16"
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="SvgDefinitions">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="HalfStar" viewBox="0 0 20 19">
      <path stroke="red" stroke-dashoffset="0" 
      
      stroke-dasharray="3.4,3.4 3.4,3.4 3.4,3.4 3.4,3.4 3.4,3.4 0, 16" 
     d="M9,0.6L6.5,5.7L0.9,6.5c-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.6,0.3c-0.4,0.4-0.4,1,0,1.4l4.1,4l-1,5.6c0,0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.6 c0.3,0.5,0.9,0.7,1.4,0.4l5.1-2.7l0,0V0C9.6,0,9.2,0.2,9,0.6z" />
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>

<svg class="Star-Container">
  <use href="#HalfStar" x-link:href="#HalfStar" />
</svg>
```

**@NodeJS by comment**

> Is there a way for the border to be continuous for the rest and not
> dashed?

To do this, swap 0, 16 by 16, 0 in the last group of parameters `stroke-dasharray`

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="SvgDefinitions">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="HalfStar" viewBox="0 0 20 19">
      <path stroke="red" stroke-dashoffset="3" 
      
      stroke-dasharray="3.4,3.4 3.4,3.4 3.4,3.4 3.4,3.4 3.4,3.4 16,0" 
     d="M9,0.6L6.5,5.7L0.9,6.5c-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.6,0.3c-0.4,0.4-0.4,1,0,1.4l4.1,4l-1,5.6c0,0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.6 c0.3,0.5,0.9,0.7,1.4,0.4l5.1-2.7l0,0V0C9.6,0,9.2,0.2,9,0.6z" />
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>

<svg class="Star-Container">
  <use href="#HalfStar" x-link:href="#HalfStar" />
</svg>
```

@Apha by comment

> Your solution doesn't have a continuous border on the left. It's
> dashed. I think the OP wanted continuous border on the left and no
> border on the right

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="SvgDefinitions">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="HalfStar" viewBox="0 0 20 19">
      <path stroke="red" stroke-dashoffset="0.75" 
      
      stroke-dasharray="33.5,0 0,16.5" 
     d="M9,0.6L6.5,5.7L0.9,6.5c-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.6,0.3c-0.4,0.4-0.4,1,0,1.4l4.1,4l-1,5.6c0,0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.6 c0.3,0.5,0.9,0.7,1.4,0.4l5.1-2.7l0,0V0C9.6,0,9.2,0.2,9,0.6z" />
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>

<svg class="Star-Container">
  <use href="#HalfStar" x-link:href="#HalfStar" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Should there be a comma between numbers?

Comment: @Node.JS  Comma separated by dash and gap digits Space separated by adjacent `stroke-dasharray` parameter groups

Comment: Is there a way for the border to be continuous for the rest and not dashed?

Comment: @Node.JS Added an example according to your comment